# C++ Standard Booleans - Switch

Tags: c++, boolean, switch-statement

It is OK to use the standard 'true' and 'false' inside a switch statement, like so:

```
void handle_a_bool (bool value_to_be_handled)
{
    switch (value_to_be_handled)
    {
        case true:
        // Yay.
        break;
        case false:
        // @$#%.
        break;
    };
};
```

I guess what I really want to know is whether the standard 'bool' type in C++ is a constant or something else.

Comment: what does your local friendly compiler say?

Comment: I compiled & ran a test program with a boolean in a switch and it seemed to work just fine. The reason I was asking about this was mainly because on a much larger project something was broken and I wondered whether it was a boolean switch statement, because the compiler was being dumb and telling me almost nothing. But since the test is fine, I guess it's a different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is legal, but why would you do that? Just use this:

```
if (value_to_be_handled)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

The version based on `switch` just makes the code harder to read and doesn't bring any additional benefit.

Comment: Actually you could have; if true do both if false just do false; if you drop a break with one for example.

Comment: @Armin: I would really dislike that. It makes it even harder to read, and it is a good programming practice to always put a `break` after a `case:`, unless you have a no-op case. It wouldn't pass code review in my team.

Comment: I am mainly looking to increase the performance of a boolean switch because I need to use several of them in a function that loops quickly.

Comment: @rsethc: This is called "premature optimization". Don't do that. First choose the simplest design, then **measure**, and if you see a bottleneck, think about optimizing it. Apart from this general principle, in this case using a `switch` won't bring you any benefit in terms of performance. Rather, it is likelier to introduce some overhead, depending on how the compiler translates the `switch` statement.

Comment: Apparently the boolean switch couldn't have been causing the problem with my project, since the test ran fine. However, I didn't think of case fall-through, which is helpful to keep in mind in case I want to further optimize something that would happen for both cases after something that would only happen for one. Thanks

Comment: @Andy there had been a previous bottleneck, and when I tried making the boolean switch statement to replace if/else's as well as changing around a lot of other stuff without running the project to debug new things (bad idea...) the compiler started acting up so I wondered whether is was the boolean switch.

Comment: Also, how can a constant switch make a bottleneck worse? I don't get that.

Comment: @rsethc: If the compiler implements `switch` through a lookup table, that would cost you one more level of indirection. Although I believe a decent compiler would optimize this into an `if ... else` (thus bringing the same performance), in case it failed to do that you would get a performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

You may use it, but as for me it's extremely hard to read.

Why to not use just

```
void handle_a_bool (bool value_to_be_handled) {
    if(value_to_be_handled) {

    }
    else{
    }
};
```

?

Comment: There's a function that has several of these true/false switches and I need the function to run as quickly as possible.